# problem creating directory: /opt/ros/kinetic

Tags: ros-kinetic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying install ROS kinetic in my Raspberry Pi 3 and have this error when I execute this command

```
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -  DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/kinetic
```

I want say that is my first time that I working with RaspberryPi

```
-- catkin 0.7.4
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:38 (file):
  file problem creating directory: /opt/ros/kinetic

Makefile:66: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
<== Failed to process package 'catkin': 
  Command '['make', 'install']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin && make install

Command failed, exiting.
```

Anyody can help me? please

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244756/problem-creating-directory:-/opt/ros/kinetic/) by [DannyMB](https://answers.ros.org/users/28114/dannymb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2016-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error message mentions

```
problem creating directory: /opt/ros/kinetic
```

Do you have enough permissions to create that directory? Try with sudo:

```
sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/kinetic
```

[image description http://i1.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/004/689/sandwich.png](http://i1.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/004/689/sandwich.png)

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2016-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DannyMB](https://answers.ros.org/users/28114/dannymb/) on 2016-09-29**:
Thanks, I am going to try it

**Comment by [VictorArias](https://answers.ros.org/users/34179/victorarias/) on 2018-04-02**:
thank you, very usefull